# force-evaluate an object being passed as an argument to a function

Tags: r, eval, evaluation

I would like to pass the value of an object as an argument to a function.

```
# This is my object
anObject <- "an_unkown_string"

# I would like to do the equivalent of: 
someFunc("an_unkown_string")

# .. by somehow calling on the object containing the string
someFunc( ??? (anObject) )
```

For example, with the sample function below  (based on `save()`):

```
someFunc <- function(...) {
  names <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  return(names)
}

# Ideally, the output would be:
someFunc( ??? (anObject) )
[1] "an_unkown_string"
```

I do not have access to modify `someFunc`
I have tried the following, but with no success.

```
 someFunc(Name_of_Object)
 someFunc(eval(Name_of_Object))
 someFunc(evalq(Name_of_Object))
 someFunc(force(Name_of_Object))
 someFunc(eval(parse(text=Name_of_Object)))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
> do.call(someFunc, list(anObject))
[1] "an_unkown_string"
```

Or you could make a wrapper

```
myWrap <- function(...) {
  do.call(someFunc, as.list(...))
}

> myWrap(anObject)
[1] "an_unkown_string"
```

---

Another way to construct a call and evaluate it:

```
> call("someFunc", anObject)
someFunc("an_unkown_string")
> eval(call("someFunc", anObject))
[1] "an_unkown_string"
```

---

I suppose I should mention that `?do.call` says

> The behavior of some functions, such as substitute, will not be the same for functions evaluated using do.call as if they were evaluated from the interpreter. The precise semantics are currently undefined and subject to change.

Nevertheless, for now at least, `anObject` is evaluated when the call is constructed (in the call to `call` or `do.call`), so `substitute` finds "an_unknown_string" instead of "anObject".

Comment: Genius!! Thank you!    What was the insight (or thought process) that lead to this solution?

Comment: Nothing other than that I probably use `do.call` too much. :-) You want to call `someFunc()` with the value of `anObject`, so, you need to construct a call.  If you give `do.call` a function and a list of arguments it calls the function with those arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled. Why are you trying to make this more complex than it realy is?

```
someFunc <- function(obj) {
   return(obj)
 }

> someFunc(anObject)
[1] "an_unkown_string"
```

Comment: `someFunc` can be any function which I dont have ownership over -- and hence, I cannot modify. I wanted to pass to it not an object but the _value_ of my object (which is actually a name to another object).  @GSee's suggestion allowed me to do just that.