# R: get an expression evaluated before passing it to a function

Tags: r

This is probably trivial, but I'm not an R expert and I am failing to find an answer.

I have some library function performing "non-standard evaluation", specifically it would be `input_fn` from the `tfestimators` library, but the following should be a valid MWE:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    substitute(x)
}
```

Now if I execute

```
val <- "value"
foo(val)
```

I get `val` as a result, which from what I get is "symbol"-typed and I can run `eval` on it to effectively get `"value"`.

But - in case `val` is some complex value I would like to reuse - how is it possible to get instead `val` evaluated to `"value"` **before** it is passed to `foo`? (without changing `foo`)

Also, can you point me to some as-quick-as-possible tutorial about this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13810001/7114235) using `do.call`

```
do.call(foo, list(val))   # returns "value"
```